# Error in hibernate bag for one-to-many mapping

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to define the bag like the following way

```
<bag name="tags" table="TAG" schema="abcd">
    <key column="TAG_ID"></key>
    <element column="TAG_ID" type="long"></element>
    <one-to-many class="com.xyzpkg.Tag" />
</bag>
```

In above case their is xml error in hbm file saying:

`The content of element type "bag" must match 
 "(meta*,subselect?,cache?,synchronize*,comment?,key,(element|one-to-many|many-to-
 many|composite-element|many-to-any),loader?,sql-insert?,sql-update?,sql-delete?,sql-
 delete-all?,filter*)".`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is because you can have either element tag or you can have one-to-many tag. Not both. Try removing the element tag.

Comment: So I can do both the things together. Do I need to define it define two bags in this case one for element and and one for mapping?